# Error encountered when installing Vue-toastification version 1.7.14 with Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to install the [Vue-toastification (**v1.7.14**)](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification) in my Vue3 app but when I build my application using `npm run build`, I face this error-

```
"default" is not exported by "../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/vue@3.3.4/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js", imported by "../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/vue-toastification@1.7.14_vue@3.3.4/node_modules/vue-toastification/dist/esm/index.js".
file: /Users/username/Documents/projectName/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/vue-toastification@1.7.14_vue@3.3.4/node_modules/vue-toastification/dist/esm/index.js:1:7
1: import Vue from 'vue';
          ^
2: 
3: /*! *****************************************************************************
error during build:
RollupError: "default" is not exported by "../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/vue@3.3.4/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js", imported by "../../../common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/vue-toastification@1.7.14_vue@3.3.4/node_modules/vue-toastification/dist/esm/index.js".
```

In my app, I am using Vue via vite-plugin, `import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'`

If I switch to [Vue-toastification **v2.0.0-rc.5**](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.5), this error is no more. But, as far as I checked, the stable version is `1.7.14` only, and that `v2.0.0` has `pre-release` tags (not stable yet but released over a year ago).

I couldn't find any issue on its GitHub repo regarding the problem in Vue3 with the `1.7.14` version so I am a little bit suspect if something is not correct with my Vite or Vue config.

I have seen the [comparison changes between version 1.7.14 and 2.0.0-rc.5](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification/compare/v1.7.14...v2.0.0-rc.5) but couldn't find anything dependency-related commit.

Is it reliable to use those v2 versions or how can I fix this for the 1.7.14 version?

Comment: In this [github](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification), It was already mentioned that If you are using Vue 2, you can go with `v1` of `vue-toastification`, for Vue 3, you have to go with `v2`. That means `v1.7.14` is not compitable with Vue 3.

Comment: But this GitHub URL is itself the v2 version of toastification whose latest version is v1.7.14. Am I correct? Please let me know.

Comment: No, v2 version means [v2.0.0-rc.5](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.5), [v2.0.0-rc.4](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.4), [v2.0.0-rc.2](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.2). I know these all version are in pre-release state but these are the only one who supports Vue 3.

Comment: Oh yes, now I got your point. Thank you so much for this information.